# IIS server unavailable on a local wifi

Tags: iis, wifi, server, lan

I want to create an IIS server on my PC. I've created a wifi hotspot through `netsh wlan set hostednetwork ...` , and a new wifi hotspot appeared (wifi2, in which my pc was 192.168.137.1). 
So I shared the connection of wifi1 (the real NIC, with ip 192.168.0.104) and I enabled sharing of HTTP service (because of the IIS server). Obviously IIS is running. wifi2 is set as a domestic net.
So, I've connected my smartphone to wifi2, and typed 192.168.137.1, the IP of my pc in wifi2, in wich it should be running the IIS server. But it respond with a timeout error. So I've typed 192.168.0.104 , the IP of wifi1, and I though my smartphone cannot reach it, because my phone is connected to wifi2, but it show the IIS home page. This is strange, but the problem is here: if I disconnect my PC from wifi1 (so there isn't an internet connection, but only a local wifi lan), from my smartphone I can't visualize anything, both 192.168.137.1 and 192.168.0.104 !

- why I need an internet connection to show the IIS page?
- How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the IP address IIS has bound the Default website is on your WiFi network, not just the hardwired...

Comment: yes, I bound the IIS default website to 192.168.137.1 . I can ping this IP from my phone, but I can't visualize the webpage on the browser

Comment: I've solved, n00b error: allowed HTTP service on windows firewall and magically worked. i'm ashamed myself... :(